# Allow percentage (%) symbol in mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to pass a PHP urlencode() variable through a mod_rewrite rule, but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

Currently I'm passing this sort of thing:

```
/test/abc%40test.co.uk
```

The @ symbol replaced with the &40 in the urlencode.

Through this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([-_.%A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ test.php?variable=$1
```

As far as I'm aware this should allow the % symbol through; why isn't it working? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is decoded before it is sent through the rewrite engine, so you need to match against `@`, and not the encoded string. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([-_.@A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ test.php?variable=$1
```

Comment: @user3420034 yes, it gets encoded in the query string again, unless you use the `NE` flag.